# Multi view controller and segue navigation error message I don't understand

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

XCode 7.3, ObjC single view project. iOS Simulator.

I'm in a UIViewController called "LoginViewController". I click a button, it calls a method called Login. In Login I call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Login" sender:sender];
```

In the performSegueWithIdentifier method I use an if statement to select on that "Login" condition and at this early stage of stubbing this out do this:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Login"]) {

     MainMenuViewController *mmvc = segue.destinationViewController;
     mmvc.strUsername = self.txtUsername.text;
     mmvc.strPassword = self.txtPassword.text;
 }
```

The MainMenuViewController loads fine and my data is visible in the UI but right after it completes the prepareForSegue method the console spits this out:

> UIView: 0x7fc19beaaf60; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = CALayer: 0x7fc19beab0d0's window is not equal to MainMenuViewController: 0x7fc19bd2d300>'s view's window!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more information about your storyboard?  I would suspect the problem is in there.

Comment: is the segue connected to button in storyboard ?

Comment: did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677447/error-uiviews-window-is-not-equal-to-another-views-window

Comment: Teja the segue is connected to a button in the MainMenuViewController that takes it back to the LoginViewController. You click it you get there. There si no identifier set on the segue in the MainMenuViewController segue that takes you back to the LoginViewController.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create the segue between the view controller's view and the next view controller rather than between a button and the next view controller. See this solution that solved the problem: [Defining a "generic" segue in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484688/defining-a-generic-segue-in-interface-builder)